# javascript mongoose dynamic model assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Ive looked related posts and couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

So I am build a backend rest api and I have certain tests I am collecting data on. The tests have their own models, and these models are associated with collections (obviously).

So I have a separate controller for each model. Now I have a "job" controller which queries data from each separate test. Now I have a separate script where I store these model objects in an JSON object. I am wondering how I can access these models properly (I am close but cant quite assign properly). Here is the block:

```
const testMappings = {
    'aprobe':aprobe,
    'status':status,
    //'rxserial':rxserial,
}
```

Now when I try assignment as follows, where testMappings is the imported script variable:

```
const testMappings = activeTests.testMappings;
console.log(testMappings['aprobe']);
```

I get the following output:

```
Model {aprobe}
```

I would like to access the actual aprobe object. Also if anyone knows a better way of dynamically assigning these (instead of having bunch of if statements ie if(name == 'aprobe').... do something), it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like below :

```
const name = 'aprobe';
Object.keys(testMappings).indexOf(name) > -1 ? testMappings[name] : null
```

the above should give you: `Model {aprobe}`

So basically if the key exists in your object then you'd like to `fetch` the value of that key which would give you your `model` dynamically.

Comment: ill give it a try and let you know!